# Detecting uncountable cardinalities, this time with determinacy

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, descriptive-set-theory

*By "small cardinality" I mean a Scott cardinality onto which $\mathbb{R}$ surjects ($0$ isn't interesting here). $\mathcal{R}=(\mathbb{R};+,\times,\mathbb{Z})$ is the field of real numbers expanded by a predicate naming the integers, and $\Sigma$ is the language of $\mathcal{R}$ plus a fresh unary relation symbol $D$ and binary relation symbol $E$. Below we work in $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD_\mathbb{R}}$.*

For a (not-necessarily-well-orderable) small cardinality $\kappa$, we say $\kappa$ is **detectable** iff there is some $\Sigma$-formula $\varphi$ such that the following are equivalent for each set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and each equivalence relation $R$ on $X$:

- $\vert X/R\vert=\kappa$.
- $\varphi$ holds in the expansion of $\mathcal{R}$ gotten by interpreting $D$ as $X$ and $E$ as $R$.

The variety of small cardinalities is enormous; see, for example, Woodin's [*The cardinals below $\vert[\omega_1]^{<\omega_1}\vert$*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007205001405). On the other hand, the theory $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD_\mathbb{R}}$ is in my experience "relatively complete" for statements about not-too-big combinatorial objects. Broadly I'm interested in what this theory can, or cannot, prove about detectability. To keep things reasonably concrete, the following seems like a good test question:

> Which of the four distinct cardinalities of $$\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\cup\omega_1,\mathbb{R}\times\omega_1,[\omega_1]^\omega$$ are detectable?

(That these are distinct is Woodin's Lemma 17, for which $\mathsf{AD_\mathbb{R}}$ is unnecessary. Woodin also includes $\omega_1$, but the detectability of $\omega_1$ is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone by an easy argument.) An [earlier question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398414/detecting-uncountable-cardinals-in-mathbbr-times-mathbbn) focused on the situation in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and I don't have any good sense about how the relevant arguments transfer (or don't) from one setting to the other.

Comment: If $|X/E| = |\mathbb{R}|$, what does $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD_\mathbb{R}}$ say about the complexity of a witness of this fact? Is it always projective?

Comment: @JamesHanson Good question, no idea.

Comment: Are you claiming that ZF+DC is sufficient to prove that the $\lvert \mathbf R\rvert<\lvert \mathbf R\cup \omega_1\rvert$?

Comment: @tomasz No (it can't possibly since $\mathsf{ZF+DC}$ is a subtheory of $\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$), but $\mathsf{AD_\mathbb{R}}$ is overkill: if you look at Woodin's paper, the cited lemma needs only $\mathsf{AD}$.

Comment: I thought as much (and that was my point, really), but your statement is a bit confusing.

Comment: I feel like morally speaking under $\mathsf{AD}$, if $|X/E| = |\mathbb{R}|$, then there ought to be a perfect set somehow witnessing this fact, like a perfect set of pairwise inequivalent elements of $X$. Is this true? If so, this would be detectable in $\mathcal{R}$ since all Borel sets are first-order definable in it, right?

Comment: More specifically, the family of perfect closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly definable in $\mathcal{R}$.

Comment: Oh, but this wouldn't differentiate the four cardinals in question, since they all should have perfect sets.